# Mysql stored procedure while loops twice

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure where I need to insert a set of data for the columns Category, Function & Status. Where category always should be '1' and Function 1 to 80, status always 'ACTIVE'.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE x  INT;
    SET x = 1;
    WHILE x  <= 80 DO
    insert into functiontocategory (category,`function`,`status`) values ('1',x,'ACTIVE');
    SET x = x+1;

    END WHILE;
END
```

But it gives me 160 rows of inserted data, where 2 sets of 1 to 80s instead of one set. what is wrong with my procedure.

Comment: you may call procedure twice, your procedure seems fine

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `test`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE X  INT;
    SET X = 1;
    WHILE X  <= 80 DO
    INSERT INTO functiontocategory (category,`function`,`status`) VALUES ('1',X,'ACTIVE');
    SET X = X+1;
    END WHILE;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

I created a database as test and a table functiontocategory (category int(3),function text,status varchar(10)) and a procedure with a name test..for testing I used call test() and it inserted 80 rows exactly

Comment: yes..like I created a database as test and a table functiontocategory (category int(3),`function` text,`status` varchar(10)) and a procedure with a name test..for testing I used call test() and it inserted 80 rows exactly..as he wants

Comment: this is not answer... you should provide solution not your test result.. any reason why rows are inserting twice??

Comment: may be due to his code in-completion..I have tried with full & proper code..'you should provide solution not your test result'..don't be imperative..I am giving the answer what I have tried & tested successfully